# Camel swf integration

Tags: apache-camel, amazon-swf

At camelone 2012 a session was on camel with amazon web Services. In particular an example was on integration with simple workflow. Where can i find the code of that example or something similar regarding these integration?
Thanks in advance F.

Comment: More explanation was provided here in http://stackoverflow.com/faq. Did you check that?

Answer (score 1):

At the Camel documentation you can find details about the camel-asw components at
http://camel.apache.org/aws.html

And about the SNS
http://camel.apache.org/aws-sns.html

And then unit tests of these components often have some examples of their usage
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/components/camel-aws/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/aws/sns/

And you can find all the videos and presentations from CamelOne 2012 at: http://fusesource.com/apache-camel-conference-2012/camelone_speakers_2012/

Comment: My question is regarding apache camel embedded in an attività worker of aws simple workflow and not on aws component in camel.

Comment: Then you should add such details to your question!